# Community Rowing website issue

Tags: wordpress

Our not-for-profit website for Harlem River Community Rowing has text running over the photo in which it was meant to be contained.  The site was created by a graphic designer, but I maintain it.  I have basic Wordpress skills and can make minor adjustments to code, but don't even know the technical terms to describe the issue in order to do research myself.  Our site is harlemrivercommunityrowing.org  The issue is visible on the main page, if you scroll to the second image in the slide show.  I would appreciate any support or direction you can give.  Thank you.

Comment: Well there is more text that fits in the box. What do you want to do with the extra text? Scroll?

Comment: Basically the answer will involve specifying the text container width or height (fixed or percentage) and/or shortening the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS rule to the `style.css` stylesheet, at the bottom. You can find this in the editor, under Appearance.

```
.featured-description {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is more of a quick fix, and really you need to modify the template file to use an excerpt rather than the full post content. But it will work fine for now.